# PHP dynamically reference object

Tags: php, oop, dynamic, reference

I'm trying to find a way to use print_r() on all of my existing objects without having to pass them as a parameter in a function manually.  Currently use this for debugging and do it this way:

```
function($obj1 as null){

// insert styling here

    print_r(get_object_vars($obj1));

// insert more styling

}
```

Right now, I have to use this function for each object on each of my pages.  It becomes a lot to manage.  It would be nice to just have one function that would use some sort of collection to output the object variables using get_object_vars.

While writing this I thought about creating a class with variables for each object.  Then in __construct for each of my classes, assign itself to the new class using that object.  However, that will be A LOT of work and seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a debugger really! But failing that I think you're right that the only real way of doing it dynamically (on all objects that exist at any one time) would be to have them register with a debug class. You could write a class which does that, and have all the other classes extend that one (although it rather steps on any existing class hierarchies you have, and might wreck the garbage collector a bit too!

Another partial solution which saves some code is at each debug call to list the objects you want outputting in an array, and looping over them.

```
foreach(array('var1', 'var2', 'var3') as $name) {
    debug($$name);
}
```

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Like the above post, using variable variables ($$) and unfortunately it doesn't work.  Here was my original method that I tried with the get_declared_classes function before asking the question.

    <?
    foreach(get_declared_classes() as $ObjectName){
    ?><br>

    <pre><? print_r(get_object_vars($$ObjectName));?></pre>
    <br> <?
    }
    ?>

Comment: In what way does it not work? I think the problem with your version is that get_declared_classes gives you a list of Classes, not of variables. If you have a variable called $var of type MyClass then MyClass will appear in get_declared_classes, but not var. Hence the variable variable will be looking for $MyClass, but won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you are looking for?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

There are many comments on that page that explain how to use the function for various purposes (one possibly relevant one being returning ONLY YOUR variables).

Even this still only does variables in the current scope and those that have been declared before the call to get_defined_vars.